# How to print data from restcontroller using AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-restcontroller

Here is my `index.html` :

```
 <script src="/teachers.js"></script>
  <table id="table-content" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Teacher ID</th>
        <th>Teacher Name</th>
        <th>Teacher Position</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`teachers.js` :

```
var service = 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1';
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: service + '/teacher/',
        // data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var trHTML = '';

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.Teacher[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data.Teacher[i].Position + '</td></tr>';
            });

            $('#table-content').append(trHTML);
        },
```

And `TeacherController` :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class TeacherController {
private static final String TEACHER_MODEL = "teacher";
@Autowired
TeacherService teacherService;


@GetMapping("/teacher")
public List<Teacher> fetchAllTeacher() {
    return teacherService.getAll();
}
```

When I get `index.html`, I just have empty table and on the page can view only name of table columns, no data..

What I do wrong and maybe you can another way for solving my problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Now I have one issue in my browser :

[image: Error]

[image: After adding port]

Errors :

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Last errors in the browser window :

```
Invalid character found in the request target [&#47;api&#47;v1&#47;teacher&#47;?47;?{}
&amp;_=1610297706796.] The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC
3986</p><p><b>Description</b>
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error ( e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

Comment: Try adding `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log( errorThrown ); }` to your ajax call, and see if that shows any ajax error. You may also have other browser console errors, already.

Comment: Your code is using `data.Teacher[i].Name` to access your JSON, but I would expect the JSON to look more like this: `[{"id":1,"name":"Bob","position":"Teacher"},{"id":2,"name":"Alice","position":"Principal"}]`. This is a guess, since the `Teacher` class is not shown.

Comment: did you check what `data` has in it ?

Comment: @andrewjames I added the picture with errors, but I don't understand how to solve it..

Comment: First things first: What port is your Spring app using? If it's the default Spring web port, I think that is 8080, or maybe 8081. In that case, try hitting your REST service directly in a new browser window by entering the address `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/teacher`. That should show you if your REST service is working, by displaying the JSON response data in your browser. Now, in your javascript, you are trying to hit `http://localhost/api/v1/teacher/` (implied port is 80) - which I expect is incorrect. So that probably needs to be fixed. After that you can re-check the error messages.

Comment: @andrewjames When I run `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/teacher`, I get my teachers on the empty page from database that I want to show in my project.

Comment: Great - then your server-side code sounds like it is OK. So, change your JavaScript to use that URL (it is missing the port number: `var service = 'http://localhost/api/v1/';`) and see if you get the same errors, or different ones.

Comment: @andrewjames I edited my URL in javascript to `var service = 'var service = 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/';` and now I have the window with errors ( I added screen to the question ) , and when I click OK on the this window, I see my `index.html` and I also don't see my teachers on the page.

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots of errors - please provide the formatted text. There is a very clear error message in part of your screenshot - but the key details are obscured: `Invalid character found in the request [something I cannot read...]...`.

Comment: Also, you haven't updated your `teachers.js` to show the latest code you are using.

Comment: @andrewjames I added screenshots because I can not copy that, so now I added message from the windows browser ( errors ) and updated `teachers.js`

Comment: This error is because of this line in your JavaScript: `data: "{}",`. This line tells jQuery that you want to send `{}` as a piece of data, from your client to the server. This data is added as a query parameter to the URL request - and I assume you do not want this, as it probably serves no purpose.

Comment: when you construct your URL you have double slash 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1//teacher' between "v1" and "teacher", I don't know ajax, but the error says that you have some invalid characters in your input. In particular "?47;?" at the end of interpreted URL seems to be a problem

Comment: @MichaelGantman - Yes, the double-slash should certainly be tidied up, but they don't cause the error. It is the ajax-specified `{}` appended as a query parameter: `http://localhost:8081/api/v1//teacher/?{}=`.

Comment: @andrewjames I updated file `teachers.js`, I don't have errors and also data is not shown

Comment: @MichaelGantman And I add edition to the question, now no errors but it also doesn't work

Comment: No errors - OK, that is progress. Now you need to fix how you are trying to access the data. See my second comment (the one about `data.Teacher[i].Name`). You can debug this with some `console.log(...);` statements and also you can see the JSON you are trying to manipulate. For example, `item.name` should give you access to each name in your existing `$.each` loop. But I do not have your JSON, so this is a guess.

Comment: Side note: If you have not seen it already, I found this article very helpful, as a general way to work through these types of problems: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @andrewjames I solved the problem.

I edited my `teachers.js` - `trHTML` line and now it is working :

```
var service = 'http://localhost:8081/';
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: service + 'teachers/',
        // data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var trHTML = '';

            $.each(data, function (i, teacher) {

                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + teacher.teacherId + '</td><td>' + teacher.teacherName + '</td><td>' + teacher.position + '</td></tr>';
            });

            $('#table-content').append(trHTML);
        },

        error: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```